# How to calculate specific cell values in python pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, calculated-columns

There is a pandas dataframe as follow:

```
import pandas as pd
raw_data = {'name': ['Willard Morris', 'Al Jennings', 'Omar Mullins', 'Spencer McDaniel'],
'age': [20, 19, 22, 21],
'favorite_color': ['blue', 'blue', 'yellow', "green"],
'grade': [88, 92, 95, 70]}

df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data)
```

I want to divide `age` and `grade` numeric cell values equal `blue` in `favorite_color` column to 125.0 value and `yellow` values divide to 130.0 and `green` to 135.0. Results mus be inserted in new columns `age_new`, `grade_new`.
By below code I receive error.

```
df['age_new'] =(df.loc[df['favorite_color']=='blue']/125.0)
df['age_new'] =(df.loc[df['favorite_color']=='yellow']/130.0)
df['age_new'] =(df.loc[df['favorite_color']=='green']/135.0)
df['grade_new'] =(df.loc[df['favorite_color']=='blue']/125.0)
df['grade_new'] =(df.loc[df['favorite_color']=='yellow']/130.0)
df['grade_new'] =(df.loc[df['favorite_color']=='green']/135.0)
```

Error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### `map`

```
mods = {'blue': 125, 'yellow': 130, 'green': 135}

df.assign(
    mods=df.favorite_color.map(mods),
    age_new=lambda d: d.age / d.mods,
    grade_new=lambda d: d.grade / d.mods
)

               name  age favorite_color  grade  mods   age_new  grade_new
0    Willard Morris   20           blue     88   125  0.160000   0.704000
1       Al Jennings   19           blue     92   125  0.152000   0.736000
2      Omar Mullins   22         yellow     95   130  0.169231   0.730769
3  Spencer McDaniel   21          green     70   135  0.155556   0.518519
```

---

#### Similar

```
mods = {'blue': 125, 'yellow': 130, 'green': 135}

df.join(df[['age', 'grade']].div(df.favorite_color.map(mods), axis=0).add_suffix('_new'))

               name  age favorite_color  grade   age_new  grade_new
0    Willard Morris   20           blue     88  0.160000   0.704000
1       Al Jennings   19           blue     92  0.152000   0.736000
2      Omar Mullins   22         yellow     95  0.169231   0.730769
3  Spencer McDaniel   21          green     70  0.155556   0.518519
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.replace` instead of `.loc`, so that you only perform the operation once.

```py
import pandas as pd

raw_data = {
    'name': ['Willard Morris', 'Al Jennings', 'Omar Mullins', 'Spencer McDaniel'],
    'age': [20, 19, 22, 21],
    'favorite_color': ['blue', 'blue', 'yellow', "green"],
    'grade': [88, 92, 95, 70]}

df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data)

color_d = {
    "blue": 125,
    "yellow": 130,
    "green": 135
}

df[["age_new", "grade_new"]] = df[["age", "grade"]].div(
    df['favorite_color'].replace(color_d), 
    axis=0)

df.head()
```

Which gives

```
    name                age favorite_color  grade   age_new     grade_new
0   Willard Morris      20  blue            88      0.160000    0.704000
1   Al Jennings         19  blue            92      0.152000    0.736000
2   Omar Mullins        22  yellow          95      0.169231    0.730769
3   Spencer McDaniel    21  green           70      0.155556    0.518519
```